# mysql_native_password not loaded

Tags: 18.04, mysql

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and I get the error when trying to enter mysql from terminal: plugin mysql_native_password not loaded.
I began getting this error after changing it from "auth_socket" to native password.
I did that while trying to fix the error "access denied to localhost".
I have google many times but cannot find a solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using actual MySQL or are you using MariaDB?  Only MariaDB has `mysql_native_password`, pure MySQL doesn't if I remember right.

Comment: I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Pure MySQL** and are **NOT** using MariaDB, then there *is* no `mysql_native_password`.

`mysql_native_password` is a MariaDB-specific thing to provide more functionality in line with the native password functions that MySQL provides.

If you are using MySQL **you do not need to set `mysql_native_password`** - just create a user with the hostname match of the wildcard to match anything, then make sure your MySQL is listening on a network socket and not just a local UNIX socket.

Comment: But how can I fix the problem? When I try to enter MySQL this error pops up.

Comment: You said you already made a change.  So do the same process again but don't set it to `mysql_native_password`?